# Two divs crossed

Tags: html, css

I would do something like this:

[image]

I did in this way ( http://jsfiddle.net/K5KjY/ ):

**CSS:**

```
#container{

    width: 970px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#backdrop-slider img{ 
    position: fixed; /* <---- Problem should be here! */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}  

#content{
    margin-top: 250px;
    width: 100%
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body lang="en">
<div id="container">

    <div id="header">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>

        <div id="backdrop-slider">
            <img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/original/fI3ucpgaVKOUcQ82vhgWmWuLlg2.jpg">
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <div id="switcher">
          <p>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div id="covers">

            <img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/zh9DXJhBdHVVaWiDURTipADamcK.jpg">

            <img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/zh9DXJhBdHVVaWiDURTipADamcK.jpg">
            <img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/zh9DXJhBdHVVaWiDURTipADamcK.jpg">
            <img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/zh9DXJhBdHVVaWiDURTipADamcK.jpg">
            <img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/zh9DXJhBdHVVaWiDURTipADamcK.jpg">
            <img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/zh9DXJhBdHVVaWiDURTipADamcK.jpg">
            <img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/zh9DXJhBdHVVaWiDURTipADamcK.jpg">
        </div>


    </div>


</div>

</body>
```

But, in this way, if I scroll down I'll get this:
[image]
I would that "backdrop-slider" goes up while scrolling down

Comment: You could add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to make it easier for us to see and understand the problem.

If I'm not mistaken, you want the top div to scroll along with the site, or not?

Comment: yes, exactly. Something like hulu.com's homepage

Comment: I've created the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K5KjY/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K5KjY/3/ Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `z-index:-1;` for the background image. (or positive index for the content)

http://jsfiddle.net/K5KjY/4/

Also, if you want the div to disappear when scrolling use `position:absolute;` instead of fixed.

Comment: No, I would that Anything scroll up. (Something like Hulu.com's homepage)

Comment: Updated fiddle. Is that ok?

Comment: If the two divs don't actually need to overlap I suggest splitting this design into three sections: title, slider, content, all having relative positions so you would avoid absolute positioning hacks :D, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/K5KjY/5/

Comment: I have splitted them in Header-Slider and Content. How I could better split them?

Comment: The html splitting is good, but you could achieve the same result without absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/K5KjY/6/

Comment: I tried. But in this way I don't get the backdrop image stick to window's margin (http://cl.ly/image/0h3c1v3x2x3c) (Look hulu.com)